# iPhone, reproduce the magnifier effect

Tags: iphone, uiview

I would like be able to create a movable magnifier (like the one you have when you copy and paste) in a custom view, for zooming a part of my view.

I have no idea on how to start, do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: Interesting question.  No ideas myself though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We do this in Crosswords. In your drawRect method, mask off a circle (using a monochrome bitmap containing the 'mask' of your magnifying glass) and draw your subject view in there with a 2x scale transform. Then draw a magnifying glass image over that and you're done.

```
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect {
    CGContextRef    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect          bounds = self.bounds;
    CGImageRef      mask = [UIImage imageNamed: @"loupeMask"].CGImage;
    UIImage         *glass = [UIImage imageNamed: @"loupeImage"];

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, bounds, mask);
    CGContextFillRect(context, bounds);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 2.0, 2.0);

    //draw your subject view here

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    [glass drawInRect: bounds];
}
```

Comment: Sounds really interesting. I will just need to add an overlay to try to mimic the reflect.
I am going to test it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: The code doesn't support a shadow on unscaled area! How to fix this?

Comment: Link to the full code (shadow isn't supported because of the code above isn't fully correct): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330975/how-to-add-a-magnifier-to-custom-control/13333807#13333807

Comment: Thank you  , have you any source code ? or sample project ?

Answer (score 4):

There is a complete example [over here](http://www.craftymind.com/2009/02/10/creating-the-loupe-or-magnifying-glass-effect-on-the-iphone/).  There is a minor error in the downloaded project but otherwise it works great and does exactly what you need.

Comment: Can you pull out the relevant bits into the answer? It looks like the link still works, but there's no guarantee as to how long that'll remain true.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code in Swift 3 :

```
class MagnifyingGlassView: UIView {

    var zoom: CGFloat = 2 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    weak var readView: UIView?

    // MARK: - UIVIew

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let readView = readView else { return }
        let magnifiedBounds = magnifyBounds(of: readView, zoom: zoom)
        readView.drawHierarchy(in: magnifiedBounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    }

    // MARK: - Private

    private func setupView() {
        isOpaque = false
        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    private func magnifyBounds(of view: UIView, zoom: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: zoom, y: zoom)
        var bounds = view.bounds.applying(transform)
        bounds.center = view.bounds.center
        return view.convert(bounds, to: self)
    }
}

extension CGRect {
    var center: CGPoint {
        get {
            return CGPoint(x: origin.x + width / 2, y: origin.y + height / 2)
        }
        set {
            origin.x = newValue.x - width / 2
            origin.y = newValue.y - height / 2
        }
    }
}
```

You need to call `setNeedsDisplay` in `scrollViewDidScroll:` if your read view is a scrollView.