# How to implement Magnifier

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, magnification

how to implement magnifier tool in cocoa using obj c

Comment: More details, please. What do you want to magnify? Something in a custom view subclass you're in control of (as in "zooming into a view"), or any point on the user's screen?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030730/iphone-reproduce-the-magnifier-effect/2030846#2030846