# How to change colors in the mirror while copying text in UIWebView on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiwebview, copy-paste

I have a UIWebView with black background and white (light gray) text. It's almost unusable while selecting text to copy, because the "mirror" is on white background color by default. Is there any way how to change this behavior?

Screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 1):

as Ben Gottlieb have already answered the question before me:

```
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect {
    CGContextRef    context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGRect          bounds = self.bounds;
    CGImageRef      mask = [UIImage imageNamed: @"loupeMask"].CGImage;
    UIImage         *glass = [UIImage imageNamed: @"loupeImage"];

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, bounds, mask);
    CGContextFillRect(context, bounds);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 2.0, 2.0);

    //draw your subject view here

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    [glass drawInRect: bounds];
}
```

for more details please check [iPhone, reproduce the magnifier effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030730/iphone-reproduce-the-magnifier-effect/2030846#2030846)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @MichaelRoland noted.