# Making a sidebar like in the Issuu-app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've been asked to see if I can make something similar to the sidebar that's available in the iOS-app made by [Issuu](https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/issuu-world-magazines.-free./id914453825?mt=8).

[image]

It's basically like any other "hamburger" swipe menu, but the main content view gets a curly 3d-transformation while the view is being moved. My question to you guys is how this 3d-transformation can be done (which libraries/frameworks should I look at) and what would you say is best practice when drawing such animations while swiping?

Edit: Video of the animation: http://mrcs.se/ZUBp

Comment: It kind of looks like a clipped version of a magnifying loupe.    e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330975/how-to-add-a-magnifier-to-custom-control

Comment: I'll take a look, but I'm not sure if it is. I managed to do a quick recording of the animation itself: http://mrcs.se/ZUBp