# xcode iOS zoom out text magnifying lens

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

2 questions:
1) When I hold my finger over text in my app, the magnifying lens displays zoomed in too much. See the word "arranged" in the image below. How do I zoom out so I can see the entire word in the magnifying glass loupe?

[image]

2) The picture below is a different app that has a custom magnifying lens. Are there easy ways to customize the magnifying lens or know an easy way to add a custom magnifying lens?
[image]

Comment: You could create your own solution and draw the selected section in a subclass view. You can find an example to get you going here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13333807/820519